# check if radio button is checked based on if it is enabled

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have a lot of radio buttons in a survey I am building, there is code in the survey to display a message if a question is missed:

```
    ElseIf Not (RadioButton237.Checked Or
            RadioButton238.Checked Or
            RadioButton239.Checked Or
            RadioButton240.Checked Or
            RadioButton241.Checked Or
            RadioButton242.Checked Or
            RadioButton243.Checked) Then

        MsgBox("You missed Question 39")
```

However, I now need this question to be greyed out in certain situations, ie: if combobox has a selection of "no" then this question is greyed out. I want the part of my code that checks for a missed question to ignore these radio buttons in that case, I have tried to do something like this:

ElseIf  ((RadioButton237.enabled = True and RadioButton237.Checked = false) or
.... then message

However it does not seem to work. Any advise is appreciated, I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `groupbox` to group the answers for a question and disabled the groupbox if combobox value is "no" or whatever...so the controls in the groupbox are disabled as well.

Then use the `GroupBox.IsEnabled` to evaluate or not the question.. I think so you get things organized are is easier to skip questions. But that´s just a quick-tip and may not be the best approach.

Comment: Mi guess is that he already has them grouped inside a container (panel, group box, etc); other radio buttons wouldn't work worrectly if all of them where directly over the form. Bur you are right that OP should check for the state of the container, not each radio button individually

Comment: thank you for your advise I was able to solve with a combination of your advise and the below answer, I like the way the greyed out panel is vs the greyed out radio buttons, thank you!

Comment: I did upvote you but b/c I have less then 15 reputation it wont show, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So did you tried something like this?

```
Elseif ((radioButton237.enabled and Not radioButton.checked) or (radioButtonXXX.enabled and Not radioButtonXXX.ckecked) or (radioButtonYYY.enabled and Not radioButtonYYY.ckecked)) then
(...)
```

Comment: i was hoping that would be the answer but it did not work, I did ElseIf ((RadioButton237.Enabled And Not RadioButton237.Checked) Or

Comment: ElseIf (Panel39.Enabled = True And Not (RadioButton237.Checked Or
        RadioButton238.Checked Or
        RadioButton239.Checked Or
        RadioButton240.Checked Or
        RadioButton241.Checked Or
        RadioButton242.Checked Or
        RadioButton243.Checked)) Then

            MsgBox("You missed Question 39")
            Exit Sub

Comment: I solved with that! thank you, I did upvote you but b/c I have less then 15 reputation it wont show, thanks again!

Comment: as a tip, you can use  "AndAlso" in place of "And" as well as "OrElse" in place of "Or" for greater efficiency - it may not matter much here but it's a good practice to get into